# Syntax error while trying to compile in Erlang, nested if statements

Tags: erlang

I am currently working on this class assignment, which is to create a btree in Erlang and create a function able to delete an Element on it. From my perspective I can't understand the error Erlang is returning me when trying to compile my code.

`btree.erl:211: syntax error before: 'end'`

Which to my knowledge isn't true, but I must be wrong? I was suspecting that it lies in the nested if clause but I tried coding the nested if statement according to here [Nested If Clause](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/erlang/erlang_nested_if_statements.htm).

I suspect it might just be a tiny issue that I am too stressed/blind to see right now. Any help would be appreciated.

```
deleteBT(BTree = {ElementAtom,Height,Links,Rechts}, Element) ->
    if 
   
        Element > ElementAtom -> 
            NeuRechts = deleteBT(Rechts, Element),
            Hanoi = findHeight(NeuRechts, Links),
            {ElementAtom,Hanoi,Links,NeuRechts};
        
        Element < ElementAtom ->    
            NeuLinks = deleteBT(Links, Element),
            Hanoi = findHeight(NeuLinks, Rechts),
            {ElementAtom,Hanoi,NeuLinks,Rechts};

        Element == ElementAtom -> 
            if 
                BTree == {ElementAtom, Height, Links,{}} -> Links;
                
                BTree == {ElementAtom, Height, {},Rechts} -> Rechts;
                
                BTree == {ElementAtom, Height, {},{}} -> {};
                
                BTree == {ElementAtom, Height, Links,Rechts} ->
                    Kleinster = kLZahl(Rechts), %Findet uns die Kleinste Zahl vom übergebenen Baum
                    RechtsNeu = deleteBT(Rechts, Kleinster), 
                    Hanoi = findHeight(RechtsNeu, Links),
                    {Kleinster, Hanoi, Links, RechtsNeu};
                true -> -1
                end;
        true -> -1;
        end.
```

Comment: I found the solution, I deleted a semicolon on the last true condition.

Comment: the last expression before an `end` must not have a `;`

Comment: Thank you jose I also just came to that exact same realisation.

Answer (score 2):

I see in your comments that you already solved the issue.

Nevertheless, I would like to use this chance to recommend you a simple way to improve your code a bit using pattern-matching and [fewer ifs](https://github.com/inaka/erlang_guidelines#avoid-if-expressions):

```
delete_bt({ElementAtom, _, Links, Rechts}, Element) when Element > ElementAtom ->
    NeuRechts = delete_bt(Rechts, Element),
    Hanoi = find_height(NeuRechts, Links),
    {ElementAtom, Hanoi, Links, NeuRechts};
delete_bt({ElementAtom, _, Links, Rechts}, Element) when Element < ElementAtom ->
    NeuLinks = delete_bt(Links, Element),
    Hanoi = find_height(NeuLinks, Rechts),
    {ElementAtom, Hanoi, NeuLinks, Rechts};
delete_bt({ElementAtom, _, Links, {}}, ElementAtom) ->
    Links;
delete_bt({ElementAtom, _, {}, Rechts}, ElementAtom) ->
    Rechts;
delete_bt({ElementAtom, Height, Height, Links, Rechts}, ElementAtom) ->
    Kleinster = kLZahl(Rechts), %Findet uns die Kleinste Zahl vom übergebenen Baum
    RechtsNeu = delete_bt(Rechts, Kleinster),
    Hanoi = find_height(RechtsNeu, Links),
    {Kleinster, Hanoi, Links, RechtsNeu};
delete_bt(_, _) ->
    -1.
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, coding this way does look a lot more readable and easier to change later on if needed. I'll try to implement that on my next assignment. But coming from Java and C, using if statements felt easier and closer to what I'm used to. Regardless, thanks for the tip.